# New Finder windows are opening in tabs when I want them to open in a new window

Tags: macos, finder, tabs

If I have a Finder window open, whenever I try to open another Finder window it opens as a new tab in previous window. The checkbox in Finder Preferences is not checked. See image below.

[image]

I'm trying to learn applescipt and i'm on the part where I open multiple Finder windows. I can't do that part as easy as it is because all I have is one open window with several tabs. How do I get folders to open in a new window?

If i open my home directory in Finder and then click on a folder, the folder contents just replaces the earlier window contents.

Comment: RE: "I'm trying to learn applescipt and i'm on the part where I open multiple Finder windows." If this is about **AppleScript**, you should probably tag the question as such and include the _code_ you are using. That said, from where are you trying to lean **AppleScript**. Are you following some online tutorial or what? Since you say you are just learning, do you know about the **AppleScript** dictionary which app's that truly support **AppleScript** have? In **Script Editor** press **⇧⌘L** to bring up the **Library** where you can then, e.g., _double-click_ on **Finder** in the **Library**...

Comment: ...to learn about its _verbs_, _nouns_, _elements_, _properties_, etc. which will hopefully give you a better understanding of the _language_ and what you can interact with **Finder** (or other applications). Applications that do not have an **AppleScript** dictionary may be able to be scripted on a limited basis using **System Events** and **UI Scripting**.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes I have an online tutorial I'm going thru.  My question wasn't really about applescript, I was just letting the reader know that it didn't work in applescript either.  My internal drive is dying but i don't know if thats the source of my problem or not! Thanks for info about the applescript dictionary.  That looks very helpful and I was not aware it existed.

Comment: Have you tried `killall Finder` in **Terminal** to see if that fixes it? When the last time you rebooted? Which online tutorial are you using for learning **AppleScript**?

Comment: @jmh there’s also such tabs windows preferences globally, in sys pref.

Comment: @user3439894 - I'm using the "Applescript The Language of Automation" tutorial excerpted from the Apple Training Series book AppleScript 1-2-3.  I've just started on it.  Do you have a better suggestion?  I'm all ears - lol.

Comment: I tried restarting the Finder and Dock and finally rebooted but it had no effect.

Comment: Did you follow up on the answer I posted? Was that the culprit?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck.  Nothing I do will cause a new location to open in a new Window, once the first Finder window is open.

Comment: Yes, the icons are still messed up in the Dock. I gave up trying to fix it!  They seem to come and go. I currently have 4 in my Dock now out of 28. Not bad but still a pain. That number varies a lot but hasn't been zero in days.

Comment: jmh, have you tried _toggling the bit_? This is where you set the setting(s) to the opposite of what they are now, logout, log back in, and _toggling the bit_ again to see if that makes any difference. Additionally, if you temporarily create a new user, login to the new user, do thing work properly in the new account?

Comment: yes, i've played with about every combination of settings.  Now i get nothing but the first open window and any folder i try to open just replaces the content with the new content in same window.  I can't get tabs and i can't get multiple windows.  i'm doing something wrong I'm sure but it hasn't hit me yet!  i'm going to keep playing with it and see what I get..  The tabs were opening in non-Finder windows. That is windows without a toobar.  But i can't figure how to open a non-Finder window now.

Comment: i just found out, and maybe I knew it already, if I open my home folder and click on one of the folders inside it. The home folder becomes the new folder. But if I right-click on a folder in my home directory i get an option to open it in new window!  I'm even more brain dead that when i started - if that was possible! lol but i can now get multiple windows!!

Comment: @user3439894 - Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @user3439894  Sorry I took so long for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on ankii's comment... Have a look at **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** under **System Preferences** > **General**<sup>1</sup> where the default setting is **In Full Screen Only**; however, it can also be set to **Always** or **Manually**.

In **Finder** > **Preferences** > **General** when **[] Open folders in tabs instead of new windows** is *unchecked*, and **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** under **System Preferences** > **General**<sup>1</sup> is set to **Always**, then **Finder** will open a new *tab* instead of a new *window*.

---

<sup>1</sup> **macOS Big Sur** and later. For **macOS Catalina** and earlier: **System Preferences** > **Dock**